# Desktop picture disappears

Tags: windows-xp, desktop, hibernate

I've put a picture on my desktop, but it disappears.

This happens when I put my laptop in hibernation mode. When I turn it on, there is blank desktop (but containing icons), and my picture reappears only after 'right click-refresh'.

How to solve this annoying problem?

Comment: What operating system? Windows? Mac? Linux?

Comment: Windows XP, I forgot to mention, sorry.

Comment: Probably a bug in the OS or a driver - my guess. Same thing happens with my dad's Vista laptop. I'm not positive if it's hibernate or sleep that causes it, but same thing; it leaves a black background that can be fixed with a refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm afraid, F5/Refresh is the best you can do ... even Microsoft's Knowledge Base doesn't have anything better to offer.

[Desktop background disappears when you resume your computer from hibernation in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/887238)

however, here are some [tips about hibernation](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-22_11-5590836.html), try reducing the load time. also a contigeous hiberfil.sys might help (kill hibernation, defragment the drive and re-enable hibernation).

Comment: But I didn't have this problem before, it started when I reinstalled Windows.

Comment: So far, this defragmentation and re-enabling hibernation helped, so, thanks :)